# Parsing an input file file in Haskell

Tags: string, file, haskell, input

Is there any fast way in Haskell to cast an input file like that into corresponding types? For example a function that takes a string and produces a list of `Int`s? Or do I need to parse it manually using `getLine` and parse the string?

```
10.
10.
[4, 3, 2, 1].
[(5,8,'~'), (6,4,'*'), (7,10,'~'), (8,2,'o')].
[4,0,9,4,7,5,7,4,6,4].
[4,10,0,6,6,5,6,5,6,2].
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the [`read`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:read) function.

Once you read in the file with `readFile` for example, you can `read` each line to convert it to the type you want. You'll have to get rid of the periods first, though. So for example:

```
main = do
    text <- readFile "test.txt"
    let cases = lines text
        -- to get rid of the periods at the end of each line
        strs = map init cases
        lastLine = read $ last strs
    print $ show (map (+5) lastLine)
```

This will take your example file and read in a list of `Int`s from the last line, and the add 5 to the whole list and print it.

If every line were the same type, you could just `map read` over all the lines to get all of them. If there are different types, like in your example, you'd have to put in some logic to figure out what type is on each line, and then call an appropriate function to deal with that type.

Comment: thank u very much it works || one of those things in haskell thet i rly like

Answer (score 4):

To build on Jeff Burka's answer, here's the specific code you would use for your particular file:

```
main = do
    [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6] <- fmap (map init . lines) $ readFile "myFile.txt"
    let myVal :: (Int, Int, [Int], [(Int, Int, Char)], [Int], [Int])
        myVal = (read l1, read l2, read l3, read l4, read l5, read l6)
    print myVal
```

This will print out the parsed tuple.

The `init` part is to get rid of the trailing period you have at the end of each line.